# FFMpeg: h.264 to h.264 with the same quality and bitrate

Tags: video, ffmpeg, h.264

I have a some mp4 video file with 1 video stream, encoded in h.264 and with bitrate XYZ kb/s, for example, let's have a name xxx.mp4 (not a home video, just a film). Its frames looks like some video data and two horizontal black strips on top and bottom side. On one of those strips there is some text, like "Our XXX super videos". I want to draw a black box on those text with dratext filter. Obviously, that processed video must be with almost same bitrate and same file size. But which options I must put in ffmpeg.exe to do so? CRF 0? CRF 18? b:v XYZ? Two-pass? VBV with  crf 23 -maxrate XYZ -bufsize 2M?
I want get video data without any losses in comprasion with original mp4 file.

Comment: Lossless is impossible in general (except your input was using lossless-mode). Assuming a black box perfectly fitting into the macroblock-grid, it might be possible in theory when modifying the encoder (heavily). Short answer: try some crf-vals and pick one which looks good. Either you sacrifice quality or compactness. Don't do anything else than crf (except hitting #bits is your top-prio) and the value itself depends on the material.

Comment: How do you think, is It possible to change each key frame with data about macroblocks in that area without re-encode whole video file?

Comment: Just use a player to deal with it. `ffplay -vf "drawbox=w=iw:h=15:t=fill" input.mp4`. Also see fillborders and crop filters.